# Long Press gesture to Alert to Save or Delete

Tags: ios, swift

Answered: Deleting an image is below in EDIT for future reference and save image was answered kindly by Matt.

I have an array of image objects (url & ID on Firebase). They are added to a scroll view. I added the long press gesture with this code:

```
func addToScroll(array:[ImageModel]) {
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        let currentImage = array[i]
        let Resource = URL(string: currentImage.url)
        let scrollWidth = self.imageScrollView.frame.size.width
        let scrollheight = self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height

        let newX =  scrollWidth * CGFloat(i)
        let imageview = SLImageView(frame: CGRect(x:((scrollWidth / 2) - 75) + newX , y:((scrollheight / 2) - 90) ,width:150, height:150))
        imageview.kf.setImage(with: Resource)
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageview.clipsToBounds = true
        imageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deleteImageAlert(_:)))
        imageview.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
        self.imageScrollView.addSubview(imageview)
        self.imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:scrollWidth + newX, height:scrollheight)
    }
}

@IBAction func deleteImageAlert(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save or Delete?", message: "Do you want to save or delete this image?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in
        let imageview = sender.view as! SLImageView
        self.saveTriggered(image: imageview.image!)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in
        let imageview = sender.view as! SLImageView
        let id2 = imageview.imageID
        self.deleteTriggered(id:id2!)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func deleteTriggered(id:String) {

    Database.database().reference().child("MeetingPhotos").child(currentMeeting.meetingID).child(id).removeValue { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
    }
    Storage.storage().reference().child("meetingPhotos").child(currentMeeting.meetingID).child(id).delete { (err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
        }
    }
}
func saveTriggered(image:UIImage) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

I'm reaching the Delete and Save now but how can I transfer the image object to the delete trigger so I can delete it on Firebase using the ID and the image itself to save trigger for a simple UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum?

EDIT:
I created a variable in the Image subclass itself for the image ID (SLImageView in my case),used to delete image in storage and database referance , fixed the code above.
Then the Firebase observer cleans and Adds subviews again

Comment: Variable and function names should start with a small letter, please: `addToScroll`, `array`, `newX`, etc. Please correct that throughout your code first. You can get in a lot of difficulty calling a variable Array when Array is the name of a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of planning ahead. It's your code; write it so that it does what you want it to do! Consider just this code (same as your code but I've cleaned it up a little, and I've reduced it so we focus on just the `saveTriggered` part for teaching purposes):

```
@IBAction func deleteImageAlert(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save or Delete?", message: "Do you want to save or delete this image?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in
        self.saveTriggered()
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
func saveTriggered() {
    print("save")
}
```

Now do some thinking. Ask yourself: What is the `sender` right at the start? It's the long press gesture recognizer. Ok, well, then its `view` is the image view to which it was added. So now we know the image view, so we know the `image`. And that's what we wanted.

So now fix your `saveTriggered` so that you can pass that image into it:

```
func saveTriggered(image:UIImage) {
    // do something with image
}
```

Finally, fix your call so that you *do* pass that image into it:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in
    let imageview = sender.view as! UIImageView
    self.saveTriggered(image:imageview.image!)
}))
```

Comment: Thank you sir .. works perfectly
Only delete func left now

Comment: I hope you are not expecting me to write it for you.